# How to add navigation to a custom Magnolia CMS template?

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I've managed to create a custom page template for Magnolia CMS pretty easily following this tutorial:

http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/templates/introduction.html

However, I'm at the point where I'd like to insert the navigation into my template but I can't find a simple way to do so. It looks like other's have had this problem with no clear way to fix it. Does anyone know how to easily include the navigation? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Magnolia CE (Community Edition) 4.5.x, you need to know that basically every page template extends the one defined in `/modules/standard-templating-kit/config/site/templates/prototype`. There you have a node, `/navigation`. You can copy that node to your new custom template, and after that you can start playing with it's properties.

But before that, don't forget to include the navigation menu(s) somewhere in your main template file (`.ftl`) and make your template to use stk model class `info.magnolia.module.templatingkit.templates.pages.STKPageModel` (add an attribute to your template named modelClass, look at stkArticle (or stkSection), it's a good place to start)

Horizontal navigation:

```
[#if def.navigation.top]
    [#include def.navigation.horizontal.template]
[/#if]
```

Vertical nav:

```
[#if def.navigation.top]
    [#include def.navigation.vertical.template]
[/#if]
```

If you want to include your menu in another template included with a `[@cms.area ...]` tag,
you can use this code:

```
[#if model.root.def.navigation.top]
    [#include model.root.def.navigation.vertical.template]
[/#if]
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad, great simply answer. Only one question for you. Should I place the navigation node under my "helloWorld" page node for it to get picked up? Does it matter where I place it in my tree?

Right now I have it at modules > templating > templates > pages > helloWorld > navigation...

having some tom cat problems so i can't test it as of yet.

Comment: Yes, actually it does matter. Just put it under "helloWorld" template node, so it can be mapped over your model class (`STKPageModel`). And I would personally suggest (I really don't know if it's better or not) to put the page template under `/modules/standard-templating-kit/templates`, because your template depends of this module (by using the `StkPageModel` class). In practice, you should create a new custom module to extend the existing standard-templating-kit module.

Comment: I'm getting an error after adding the modelClass "Error while rendering [/hello] with template [templating:pages/helloWorld]: RenderException: info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException: Can't instantiate model: class info.magnolia.module.templatingkit.templates.pages.STKPageModel"

Comment: 1. What version of Magnolia do you have? 2. Do you have stk installed? (look in your /config/modules for a node called standard-templating-kit)

Comment: We sorted it out - we're running 4.5 of the community edition. thank you for your help!

Comment: I just did what you said, but I got following error:

    2015-10-26 17:44:07,543 ERROR info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderingFilter    : Guice configuration errors:

1) RD cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

1 error
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) RD cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

1 error
 at com.google.inject.internal.MoreTypes.canonicalizeForKey(MoreTypes.java:78)
 at com.google.inject.Key.<init>(Key.java:126)
 at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:256)
 ...